# Why does LVM mirror rebuild after brief disk disconnect?

Tags: lvm, raid1, mirror

I have 2 external disks connected to a Fedora 29 system via USB3. They are set up in an LVM RAID1 configuration.

When 1 disk is disconnected, power outage, USB issue, etc, the entire RAID array rebuilds. There are 3 logical volumes in the VG that is mirrored, with a total of about 8TBs, so the rebuilds take days.

What is the reason that the mirrors are rebuilt from 0% every time a disk is removed, regardless of if the data has changed/etc. Is lvmd not "smart" enough to pick up from where the mirror was previously and do a small "incremental" sync to bring the mirror back in line?

Additional Information:

```
# lvs -a -o name,copy_percent,devices vg-media
LV                   Cpy%Sync Devices                                    
movies               3.53     movies_rimage_0(0),movies_rimage_1(0)      
[movies_rimage_0]             /dev/sdd(0)                                
[movies_rimage_0]             /dev/sdd(1726464)                          
[movies_rimage_0]             /dev/sdd(1918467)                          
[movies_rimage_1]             /dev/sde2(128002)                          
[movies_rimage_1]             /dev/sde2(1918467)                         
[movies_rmeta_0]              /dev/sdd(1918465)                          
[movies_rmeta_1]              /dev/sde2(128001)                          
own_cloud            50.61    own_cloud_rimage_0(0),own_cloud_rimage_1(0)
[own_cloud_rimage_0]          /dev/sdd(1598464)                          
[own_cloud_rimage_0]          /dev/sdd(1880064)                          
[own_cloud_rimage_1]          /dev/sde2(1)                               
[own_cloud_rmeta_0]           /dev/sdd(1918464)                          
[own_cloud_rmeta_1]           /dev/sde2(0)                               
plex                 100.00   plex_rimage_0(0),plex_rimage_1(0)          
[plex_rimage_0]               /dev/sdd(1688064)                          
[plex_rimage_1]               /dev/sde2(1880067)                         
[plex_rmeta_0]                /dev/sdd(1918466)                          
[plex_rmeta_1]                /dev/sde2(1880066)
```

```
dmsetup table | grep media
vg--media-plex: 0 314572800 raid raid1 3 0 region_size 4096 2 253:16 253:17 253:18 253:19
vg--media-movies: 0 15032385536 raid raid1 3 0 region_size 8192 2 253:6 253:7 253:8 253:9
vg--media-plex_rimage_1: 0 314572800 linear 8:66 15401574399
vg--media-movies_rimage_1: 0 14352908288 linear 8:66 1048657919
vg--media-movies_rimage_1: 14352908288 679477248 linear 8:66 15716147199
vg--media-plex_rimage_0: 0 314572800 linear 8:48 13828622336
vg--media-movies_rimage_0: 0 13094617088 linear 8:48 2048
vg--media-movies_rimage_0: 13094617088 1258291200 linear 8:48 14143195136
vg--media-movies_rimage_0: 14352908288 679477248 linear 8:48 15716083712
vg--media-own_cloud_rimage_1: 0 1048576000 linear 8:66 73727
vg--media-own_cloud_rimage_0: 0 734003200 linear 8:48 13094619136
vg--media-own_cloud_rimage_0: 734003200 314572800 linear 8:48 15401486336
vg--media-plex_rmeta_1: 0 8192 linear 8:66 15401566207
vg--media-movies_rmeta_1: 0 8192 linear 8:66 1048649727
vg--media-own_cloud: 0 1048576000 raid raid1 3 0 region_size 4096 2 253:11 253:12 253:13 253:14
vg--media-plex_rmeta_0: 0 8192 linear 8:48 15716075520
vg--media-movies_rmeta_0: 0 8192 linear 8:48 15716067328
vg--media-own_cloud_rmeta_1: 0 8192 linear 8:66 65535
vg--media-own_cloud_rmeta_0: 0 8192 linear 8:48 15716059136
```

Comment: You need to create a "write intent bitmap".  How you do it depends on if you're using MDraid (`mdadm`) for the RAID array and layering LVM on top of it, or if you're using LVMraid directly.   This bitmap allows for changes to the active disks to be tracked and for the re-added disk to be quickly brought into sync.  Without this bitmap there's no information to tell the system how far the disk is out of sync and so it needs to be fully rebuilt.

Comment: What are the outputs of `lvs -a -o name,copy_percent,devices yourvgname` and `dmsetup table`?

Comment: Updated the question with additional output from those commands. I believe I am using LVMRaid directly. Is there a manual way to create the missing bitmap? I assumed that was done at lvm mirror creation time.

Comment: Not all three LVs are rebuilt, it seems. `plex` is completely in sync, `own_cloud` at 50%, and `movies` hardly at all. Would be interesting if these values change over time. Maybe they are still syncing from the last boot?

Comment: Yes, the resync takes hours when there is a disconnect. The largest volume `movies` is almost done, at 97% now. I have found information on the write intent bitmap when using mdraid, however, everything I understand about LVMraid (what was used here) says the bitmap is created and stored automatically.
Is there a way to check on the LVMRaid bitmap?

Comment: I do not know how LVM works internally. I assume that the `rmeta` LVs are mapped before the `rimage` containers. `mdadm` cannot handle superblocks which are on a different device (RAID containers may be an exception; I am not familiar with them). So you could manually create a DM blockdevice using `dmsetup` with such a mapping and have `mdadm` examine that. In general ist may be a good idea (if there is still space) to create a small RAID LV for testing purposes.